# How do I keep an SqlConnection open for the entire time that the ASP.NET application is running?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

In examples of interacting with the database in ASP.NET I always see

```
using ( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString) )
{
   // ... Do some stuff
}
```

but I'm wondering, shouldn't I just be connected all the time? It doesn't make sense why I would want all the overhead involved in opening and closing connections. Shouldn't `con` be like a `static` member of my model?

Comment: You want Connection Pooling; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973151

Comment: No, you do not want to do this. Refer some answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811899/how-should-one-maintain-a-database-connection-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659228/is-it-expensive-to-keep-database-connections-open)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SqlConnection` is not thread-safe.

Since ASP.Net requests can arrive on multiple threads, you must not do that.

SqlConnection is [already pooled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx); you don't have anything to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, you do not want to leave a connection open if you are not using it. It is much cleaner to use a Using statement when connecting to a DB. There is a good discussion here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072583/is-it-ok-to-leave-a-sql-connection-open